VSCode Linker can not find ARM GNU Commands to write/read
Hi Guys sorry but this is my first time trying to setup ARM GNU On my Mac-OS Apple Sillicon M1.  I am having trouble with it as the linker fails to find the commands listed in the screenshot
So far i have installed ARM GNU 12.3
ARM GNU CMSI 5.9.0
this is the main.c File
#include "LPC845.h"
void SystemInit(void)
{
SYSCON->FROOSCCTRL |= (1 << 17);
SYSCON->FRODIRECTCLKUEN = 0;
SYSCON->FRODIRECTCLKUEN = 1;
SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL0 |= (1 << 20);
GPIO->DIRSET[1] = 0x00000007;
GPIO->SET[1] = (1 << 0);
GPIO->SET[1] = (1 << 1);
GPIO->SET[1] = (1 << 2);
}
void delay(uint32_t del)
{
uint32_t i;
for (i = 0; i < del; i++)
{
__asm("nop");
}
}
int main(void)
{
while (1)
{
GPIO->NOT[1] = (1 << 1);
delay(100000);
}
return 0;
}

I am using the following command to run the main.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -O0 -g3 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -I..\Include main.c
startup_LPC845.S "-Wl,--no-warn-rwx-segments" -lc -lrdimon -T LPC845_flash.ld -o
main.el

and then the followin command for OpenOCD
..\OpenOCD\openocd -s ..\OpenOCD\scripts -f \interface\cmsis-dap.cfg -f \target\
LPC84x.cfg -c 'adapter speed 2000' -c "program main.elf reset exit"


so far i have tried /done the following
exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit' when using arm-none-eabi-gcc

so you want to cross compile for a microcontroller?   bare metal (no operating system) but want to have a C library (that needs an operating system or at least system calls like open, close, etc?)

what C library are you linking in?  (Determines how to resolve the system calls)(you could just create dummy functions with those names and link it in)

start off by getting rid of the -lc and see if that resolves the missing operating system stuff.

do not program the mcu until at least the build/link is clean.  depending on the board you can easily brick it, sometimes recoverable, sometimes recoverable with extra tools, sometimes not.

I dont know what lrdimon is but you probably do not need it either, this code is very simple and you just need the bare minimum to call these functions, these functions do all the work.

Through the great pain that is vendor libraries and cmsis I/you/we can see at least your code above being compiled into an object.
arm-none-eabi-gcc -I.  -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb   -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <SystemInit>:
   0:   2280        movs    r2, #128    @ 0x80
   2:   4b0e        ldr r3, [pc, #56]   @ (3c <SystemInit+0x3c>)
   4:   0292        lsls    r2, r2, #10
   6:   6a99        ldr r1, [r3, #40]   @ 0x28
   8:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
   a:   430a        orrs    r2, r1
   c:   629a        str r2, [r3, #40]   @ 0x28
   e:   2200        movs    r2, #0
  10:   2101        movs    r1, #1
  12:   2080        movs    r0, #128    @ 0x80
  14:   631a        str r2, [r3, #48]   @ 0x30
  16:   2280        movs    r2, #128    @ 0x80
  18:   6319        str r1, [r3, #48]   @ 0x30
  1a:   581c        ldr r4, [r3, r0]
  1c:   0352        lsls    r2, r2, #13
  1e:   4322        orrs    r2, r4
  20:   501a        str r2, [r3, r0]
  22:   23a0        movs    r3, #160    @ 0xa0
  24:   4a06        ldr r2, [pc, #24]   @ (40 <SystemInit+0x40>)
  26:   061b        lsls    r3, r3, #24
  28:   3879        subs    r0, #121    @ 0x79
  2a:   5098        str r0, [r3, r2]
  2c:   4a05        ldr r2, [pc, #20]   @ (44 <SystemInit+0x44>)
  2e:   5099        str r1, [r3, r2]
  30:   3101        adds    r1, #1
  32:   5099        str r1, [r3, r2]
  34:   3102        adds    r1, #2
  36:   5099        str r1, [r3, r2]
  38:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
  3a:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  3c:   40048000    andmi   r8, r4, r0
  40:   00002384    andeq   r2, r0, r4, lsl #7
  44:   00002204    andeq   r2, r0, r4, lsl #4

00000048 <delay>:
  48:   2800        cmp r0, #0
  4a:   d004        beq.n   56 <delay+0xe>
  4c:   2300        movs    r3, #0
  4e:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  50:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  52:   4298        cmp r0, r3
  54:   d1fb        bne.n   4e <delay+0x6>
  56:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   20a0        movs    r0, #160    @ 0xa0
   2:   2202        movs    r2, #2
   4:   4904        ldr r1, [pc, #16]   @ (18 <main+0x18>)
   6:   0600        lsls    r0, r0, #24
   8:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   @ (1c <main+0x1c>)
   a:   5042        str r2, [r0, r1]
   c:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
   e:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
  10:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  12:   d1fb        bne.n   c <main+0xc>
  14:   e7f8        b.n 8 <main+0x8>
  16:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  18:   00002304    andeq   r2, r0, r4, lsl #6
  1c:   000186a0    andeq   r8, r1, r0, lsr #13

We can work from this
You are trying to do a simple blinker and that is excellent this is exactly where you want to start...And looks like you have gcc/binutils installed and working and that is a first milestone.  If openocd is installed and working then another major milestone.
I do not have your startup file and do not want/need it, we can work from this.  There is no .data nor .bss so that makes it easier.  I am not going to figure out nor create an NXP account to get the users manual, but the datasheet is free and shows the memory map.  I have used NXP cortex-m parts and we use 0x00000000 for the flash and 0x10000000 for the ram.
flash.s
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x10001000
.word reset     

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl SystemInit
    bl main
    b .

flash.ld
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
}

build
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -T flash.ld flash.o main.o -o main.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin

Now the problem is that main is too thin it looks like it optimized out the register writes.
This should lead you to blinking led success then you can complicate this as you desire with vendor libraries and cmsis.
build
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0plus flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -c main.c -o main.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -T flash.ld flash.o main.o -o main.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin

You likely do not need the -nostdlib and freestanding and all that you will get the same result.  Those are, if needed, for more complicated code (struct = struct the toolchain adds a call to memcpy assuming you have a C library rather than a loop, as an example)
You can try this main.elf with your openocd command and see what happens.
I have a concern with that main code output but I do not have the users guide, and further want to show something...take it or leave it...
#include "LPC845.h"

unsigned int f00 ( void )
{
return(GPIO->NOT[1]);
}
00000000 <f00>:
   0:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    @ c <f00+0xc>
   4:   e5930304    ldr r0, [r3, #772]  @ 0x304
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   c:   a0002000    andge   r2, r0, r0

Yeah, okay I see, that is fine...0xA0002000 it was generating an 0xA0xxxxxx address and I was expecting some 0x4xxxxxxx based one.
I can repeat that for all these addresses
unsigned int f00 ( void ) { return(GPIO->NOT[1]); } a0002000  0x304
unsigned int f01 ( void ) { return(SYSCON->FROOSCCTRL); } 40048000  0x28
unsigned int f02 ( void ) { return(SYSCON->FRODIRECTCLKUEN); } 40048000 0x30
unsigned int f03 ( void ) { return(SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL0); }40048000  0x80
unsigned int f04 ( void ) { return(GPIO->DIRSET[1]); }a0002000  0x384
unsigned int f05 ( void ) { return(GPIO->NOT[1]); }a0002000 0x304
unsigned int f06 ( void ) { return(GPIO->SET[1]); }a0002000 0x204

Here is some actual code for an NXP mcu that works...You can choose to take this approach or not, the abstraction has decades of experience behind it, from my mentors through me.  It will still get some flames...
extern unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
extern void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
extern void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define GPIODIRP0  0xA0002000
#define GPIOSETP0  0xA0002200
#define GPIOCLRP0  0xA0002280
#define GPIONOTP0  0xA0002300

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(GPIODIRP0);
    //ra|=1<<10;
    ra|=1<<14;
    ra|=1<<15;
    ra|=1<<16;
    ra|=1<<17;
    PUT32(GPIODIRP0,ra);

    PUT32(GPIOSETP0,(1<<14)|(1<<16));
    PUT32(GPIOCLRP0,(1<<15)|(1<<17));

    while(1)
    {
        PUT32(GPIONOTP0,(1<<14)|(1<<15)|(1<<16)|(1<<17));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }

    return(0);
}

flash.s
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x10001000  /* 0x00 */
.word reset       /* 0x04 */
.word hang        /* 0x08 */
.word hang        /* 0x0C */

.word hang        /* 0x10 */
.word hang        /* 0x14 */
.word hang        /* 0x18 */
.word hang        /* 0x1C */

.word hang        /* 0x20 */
.word hang        /* 0x24 */
.word hang        /* 0x28 */
.word hang        /* 0x2C */

.word hang        /* 0x30 */
.word hang        /* 0x34 */
.word hang        /* 0x38 */
.word hang        /* 0x3C */

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr

flash.ld
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}

build it
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin

then use the .elf or .bin depending on how you load (openocd or drop and drag the bin file to a virtual flash on the debugger).
From this I had clearly read the manual this was the minimal, the gpio apparently is enabled on reset and does not need extra bits set (or at least port 0 perhaps).  And can go right into poking bits.  I forget the name of it but this is a cortex-m way of doing read-modify-write for you on vendor registers.
The math for this is in various documents on how they generate that address.  Good that there appears to be some consistency across NXP products, some vendors not so much.
Port 0 on one part
#define GPIODIRP0  0xA0002000
#define GPIOSETP0  0xA0002200
#define GPIOCLRP0  0xA0002280
#define GPIONOTP0  0xA0002300

Port 1 on another
#define GPIO_DIRSET  0xa0002384
#define GPIO_NOT1    0xa0002304
#define GPIO_SET1    0xa0002204

So unless P1 needs an enable after reset
notmain.c
extern unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
extern void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
extern void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define GPIODIRP1  0xA0002004
#define GPIOSETP1  0xA0002204
#define GPIOCLRP1  0xA0002284
#define GPIONOTP1  0xA0002304

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(GPIODIRP1);
    ra|=1<<0;
    ra|=1<<1;
    ra|=1<<2;
    PUT32(GPIODIRP1,ra);

    PUT32(GPIOSETP1,(1<<2)|(1<<1)|(1<<0));

    while(1)
    {
        PUT32(GPIONOTP1,(1<<1)));
        for(ra=0;ra<100000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }

    return(0);
}

flash.s
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x10001000
.word reset     

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr

flash.ld
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
}

No other files needed but those three, no cmcis (yay!) no vendor libraries.
And your toolchain.
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin

inspect
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf 

notmain.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   10001000    andne   r1, r0, r0
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   f000 f806   bl  18 <notmain>
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <reset+0x4>

0000000e <PUT32>:
   e:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
  10:   4770        bx  lr

00000012 <GET32>:
  12:   6800        ldr r0, [r0, #0]
  14:   4770        bx  lr

00000016 <dummy>:
  16:   4770        bx  lr

00000018 <notmain>:
  18:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  1a:   480c        ldr r0, [pc, #48]   @ (4c <notmain+0x34>)
  1c:   f7ff fff9   bl  12 <GET32>
  20:   2107        movs    r1, #7
  22:   4301        orrs    r1, r0
  24:   4809        ldr r0, [pc, #36]   @ (4c <notmain+0x34>)
  26:   f7ff fff2   bl  e <PUT32>
  2a:   2107        movs    r1, #7
  2c:   4808        ldr r0, [pc, #32]   @ (50 <notmain+0x38>)
  2e:   f7ff ffee   bl  e <PUT32>
  32:   4d08        ldr r5, [pc, #32]   @ (54 <notmain+0x3c>)
  34:   2102        movs    r1, #2
  36:   4808        ldr r0, [pc, #32]   @ (58 <notmain+0x40>)
  38:   f7ff ffe9   bl  e <PUT32>
  3c:   2400        movs    r4, #0
  3e:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  40:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  42:   f7ff ffe8   bl  16 <dummy>
  46:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
  48:   d1f9        bne.n   3e <notmain+0x26>
  4a:   e7f3        b.n 34 <notmain+0x1c>
  4c:   a0002004    andge   r2, r0, r4
  50:   a0002204    andge   r2, r0, r4, lsl #4
  54:   000186a0    andeq   r8, r1, r0, lsr #13
  58:   a0002304    andge   r2, r0, r4, lsl #6

and that looks good.  Unless you need to enable p1 then that should light and blink your leds.
Your delay is not what we normally see, folks usually come here because the delay is dead code.  asm nop is not a bad choice...
extern void dummy ( unsigned int );

void delay0 (unsigned int del)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < del; i++)
    {
    }
}

void delay1 (unsigned int del)
{
    volatile unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < del; i++)
    {
    }
}

void delay2 (unsigned int del)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < del; i++)
    {
        __asm("nop");
    }
}

void delay3 (unsigned int del)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < del; i++)
    {
        dummy(i);
    }
}

void fun0 ( void ) { delay0(10000); }
void fun1 ( void ) { delay1(10000); }
void fun2 ( void ) { delay2(10000); }
void fun3 ( void ) { delay3(10000); }


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <delay0>:
   0:   4770        bx  lr
   2:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)

00000004 <delay1>:
   4:   2300        movs    r3, #0
   6:   b082        sub sp, #8
   8:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
   a:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
   c:   4298        cmp r0, r3
   e:   d905        bls.n   1c <delay1+0x18>
  10:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  12:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  14:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  16:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  18:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  1a:   d3f9        bcc.n   10 <delay1+0xc>
  1c:   b002        add sp, #8
  1e:   4770        bx  lr

00000020 <delay2>:
  20:   2800        cmp r0, #0
  22:   d004        beq.n   2e <delay2+0xe>
  24:   2300        movs    r3, #0
  26:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  28:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  2a:   4298        cmp r0, r3
  2c:   d1fb        bne.n   26 <delay2+0x6>
  2e:   4770        bx  lr

00000030 <delay3>:
  30:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  32:   1e05        subs    r5, r0, #0
  34:   d006        beq.n   44 <delay3+0x14>
  36:   2400        movs    r4, #0
  38:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  3a:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  3c:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <dummy>
  40:   42a5        cmp r5, r4
  42:   d1f9        bne.n   38 <delay3+0x8>
  44:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
  46:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)

00000048 <fun0>:
  48:   4770        bx  lr
  4a:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)

0000004c <fun1>:
  4c:   2300        movs    r3, #0
  4e:   b082        sub sp, #8
  50:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  52:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  54:   4a05        ldr r2, [pc, #20]   @ (6c <fun1+0x20>)
  56:   4293        cmp r3, r2
  58:   d805        bhi.n   66 <fun1+0x1a>
  5a:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  5c:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  5e:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  60:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  62:   4293        cmp r3, r2
  64:   d9f9        bls.n   5a <fun1+0xe>
  66:   b002        add sp, #8
  68:   4770        bx  lr
  6a:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  6c:   0000270f    .word   0x0000270f

00000070 <fun2>:
  70:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    @ (7c <fun2+0xc>)
  72:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  74:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
  76:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  78:   d1fb        bne.n   72 <fun2+0x2>
  7a:   4770        bx  lr
  7c:   00002710    .word   0x00002710

00000080 <fun3>:
  80:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  82:   2400        movs    r4, #0
  84:   4d03        ldr r5, [pc, #12]   @ (94 <fun3+0x14>)
  86:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  88:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  8a:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <dummy>
  8e:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
  90:   d1f9        bne.n   86 <fun3+0x6>
  92:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
  94:   00002710    .word   0x00002710

the optimizer wipes out the dead code.
00000048 <fun0>:
  48:   4770        bx  lr
  4a:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)

You can see the difference in size of the volatile code and the asm nop code.
The actual loops
  5a:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  5c:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  5e:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  60:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  62:   4293        cmp r3, r2
  64:   d9f9        bls.n   5a <fun1+0xe>

If you try to count clocks from number of instructions...You will fail...you can thank me later for that before you pull all your hair out trying to make it work.
vs the nop loop
  72:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
  74:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
  76:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  78:   d1fb        bne.n   72 <fun2+0x2>
  

The volatile one is going to burn a lot more clock cycles for the same number of loops.  Counter based loops like this, except for very specific platforms, are not going to produce exact delay times, but for the hello world of mcus (just blink an led) this works fine, you can tune-ish but not to an exact blink rate.
If you avoid the compile domain and avoid the optimizer then it has to generate the code.
  86:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  88:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  8a:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <dummy>
  8e:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
  90:   d1f9        bne.n   86 <fun3+0x6>

this will be slower than the nop solution but should be faster than the volatile.
A fun one is.
.thumb_func
.globl delay
delay:
    sub r0,#1
    bne delay
    bx lr

faster and cleaner than the others.  with gnu/llvm if built as unified syntax then use subs if not unified syntax then sub.  (stuff that will crash your mcu not knowing the tools and what to look for so, your asm loop is fine, you might have to tweak the syntax as inline asm is not part of the C standard (each compiler vendor can choose the exact syntax)).
I do not know what your startup code is that you are using (from reset to main() or reset to SystemInit in your case), I doubt it uses a C library, that would be a very good reason to run far away from it.   Your -lc in the command line you are trying to link a c library.  You should avoid the C library like the plague with bare metal.  Particularly printf() as it is so massive with the amount of code it sucks in.   You do want to eventually optimize if not always -O2 not -O0.
I would try to remove other things from that command line and see what happens.  If you are going to use cmsis or a vendor library then you may be stuck with their bootstrap code which means you are stuck with their linker script and these are all part of the nightmare but there are times where that path is...easier...(until it fails then it fails MASSIVELY even costing you your job sometimes).
When the linker (ld in the gnu world) starts complaining about write, open, etc.  That means that a C library was linked in but nothing behind it (an operating system).  This is bare metal so you have no operating system.   I strongly recommend linking directly and not have gcc call it, but there are folks code that won't work that well that way.  The linker does not know where things are and gcc does so sometimes it is easier but even there I make a separate call to gcc as a link step than some all in one thing.  Newlib is a popular C library that by putting some dummy code in a single file you can resolve all of those functions and gain things like memcpy and such.  with a few more lines of code can get sprintf to work and maybe printf if you connect the write() to stdout to a uart or something.  If you did not build newlib and link it in then you probably have glibc, which clearly can also have a backend solution but I have not done it.  I stopped using C libraries in my bare metal 20 years ago.  And have had a much happier and more successful life.
99% of bare metal is not writing the application, it is reading and for lack of another term hacking.  The docs are buggy, plan for it, protect yourself, the libraries are ... bad, buggy ... plan for it and protect yourself.  And when doing something like this taking some code you found or creating some code and trying to build it with commands you have seen...end of the day you have to beat the toolchain into submission.  the gnu tools while do not produce the best code, and their code has gotten worse over the years, is still a very very powerful toolchain as binutils all by itself makes it easy as you can see from only one tool, can debug your binary long before you crash or worse brick the board.
readelf and others are there too and have great value.  Other toolchains do not necessarily offer disassemblers nor file formats that binutils can read.  And the volume of users and examples out there are basically gnu based.  So master that toolchain first, and then maybe you do not need another.  (note that gnu varies by target, more common that not but riscv, xtensa, msp430, etc, etc have nuances, arm dominates the processor world by an order of magnitude so...you are on the right path).
Oh, I guess I cannot demonstrate this party trick...
delay1

  10:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  12:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  14:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  16:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  18:   4283        cmp r3, r0
  1a:   d3f9        bcc.n   10 <delay1+0xc>

fun 1

  5a:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  5c:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  5e:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
  60:   9b01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  62:   4293        cmp r3, r2
  64:   d9f9        bls.n   5a <fun1+0xe>

I saw one of the toolchains, would had to have been gcc not clang, but the inlined version did not remove the code as dead code, but also did not honor the volatile (assuming you know what volatile means, and you cannot possibly because the C language world cannot agree on its definition over the decades)
The day it happened the inlined version was more like the ultimate desire for a loop like that
fun 1

  5c:           adds    r3, #1
  62:           cmp r3, r2
  64:           bne 5c <fun1+0xe>

It might have had one read or write in it or a write after, but it had undone some of the volatile.  (the external function still had it in there, was very strange, I wish I could repeat it). Definitely do not want to rely on it.  Before loading the binary even with your nop solution. Check the disassembly of the delay loop to make sure you are getting a delay and are not going to drive yourself crazy.  You do not need to know the gory details of assembly language/machine code (it will greatly enhance your career though) but if you see a simple return
00000000 <delay0>:
   0:   4770        bx  lr

that is not a delay you can see.
With some work you should be able to turn your code plus vendor plus cmsis into a working binary. do not try to load it into the mcu until the toolchain builds clean.
__write, open etc means missing C library then ask am I using a C library and if so why.  Some of those nostdlib and others help remove compiler or linker added C library code (memcpy) that you may not want and can cause your link to fail.
If it is like _addd3 or something that is not C library that is GCC library libgcc  or -lgcc.  I do not think any processor can do every math operation in its native instruction set.  But the C language allows it, 64 bit division math on an 8 bit mcu is perfectly legal.  So the compiler of the C language has to generate functional code for that C code even if that includes a library call not just a few instructions, if you are not doing this math you won't see it, if you are then you need to add libgcc which can be tricky because ld does not know where it is positionally on the hard drive and cannot say go up a few then down this path to find libgcc, where gcc can so that is one reason to use gcc as your linker not ld  or directly path to the libgcc.a.
The cortex m then puts you in another pickle there because there are multiple instruction sets basically armv6-m and armv7-m all of them can run the armv6-m instructions but only some the armv7-m (the m0+ cannot for example)  and first is getting gcc to build all the combinations and then second is finding which one to link in.  (or just avoid that math, do it in fixed point with 32 bit numbers, never divide, only sometimes multiply).
You are on the right path, have fun.

I just want to first say , Thank you . I cant thank you enough for taking your time to write such a lengthy and descriptive paragraph which i havent even been able to go through completly. Im gnna go through this and get back to you. And yes i am writing for a Micocontroller. And i only used -lc because i faced the issue and saw somewhere that it might fix/ignore or bypass the issue . Il keep you updated

get the nxp docs and the arm docs (cortex-m0 plus technical reference manual and that leads to the armv6-m architectural reference manual).  your binary needs to start with a 32 bit value that is the stack init value 0x10001000 in my example and then the address ORRED with one of the reset vector.   Then you need code at that vector, those are your first instructions.   Those are or should be in assembly, among other things they are the bootstrap that prepares the system to run C code.  Your code needs almost nothing there, stack pointer (handled by the vector table) and call main

well you are leveraging a design I guess that SystemInit is called then main or you could have main call system init and the bootstrap only needs to call main.  In any case, use the power of the binutils tools, readelf, objdump, objcopy, etc to see what it is building, you can dump objects as well as the end binary to see what calls are being made to see perhaps why the linker is complaining.   your code  (main.c or whatever you called it) should have no library calls, as written, so it should need very little else to link with (just something to start it)...

knowing the building blocks is IMO part of the job and once you know them, then you can both debug a build as well as develop the binary to walk through those steps...
